# How to organize folder structure for fabric chaincode using library or utility functions?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Fabric chaincode requires separate folders for each chaincode for deployment.
for e.g., chaincode_1 will need to be in chaincode_1 folder with all the dependencies (vendor), util/library functions + chaincode_1.go and same for chaincode_2.

My question is how to organize util/library folder if it has functions that i want to use it across chaincodes.  Fabric chaincode deployment does not allow it.. i think. And the util folder is replicated/redundant in each chaincode folder

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of your shared dependencies, including your own util package, in a separate repository and then vendor them via [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep). They would still be replicated per chaincode, but it might be easier to manage them via dep ensure rather than having to manually copy them.